# Why multiple choice autocomplete with jQuery and PHP does not work?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I want to use a [multiple autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) in my form using jQuery, PHP, and MySQL. But it does not work for me. Do I have any mistake ?

---

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$( "#countries" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })

        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "process/find_countries.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**PHP code**

```
    $result = array();
    $term = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
    $sql = "SELECT title FROM tbl_countries WHERE title LIKE ?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array('%'.$term.'%'));
    $rows = $q->rowCount();
    echo($rows);
    while ($r = $q->fetch())
    {
        array_push($result,array('label'=>$r['title'], 'value'=>$r['title']));
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Any errors showing in the console?

Comment: in the url.. remove the last part and add `process/find_countries.php` to see what shows

Comment: Try to change `'lable'=>$r['title'],` to `'label'=>$r['title'],`

Comment: Do you mean `{
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response` ?

Comment: @Engineer I corrected it. But nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see in firebug response from server . and why you do echo($rows); ?